# When to use ∂ and when to use the g-type for little д?

Tags: алфавит

I'm always unsure as to how to choose to write д in my handwriting.

- Can one arbitrarily choose between ∂ and the minuscule (little *g*-type) here shown? (I mean, sticking to one of them for the whole text, but is it otherwise arbitrary?)

[image: Handwritten cursive Д in both uppercase and lowercase, the lowercase is in the from of a lowercase latin "g"]

Comment: Good question, actually. I use ∂ in handwriting whenever I can, *just because* I can, and *just because* it sticks out. I'm a rebel like that. But I have no idea why they teach the one and not the other. I will add that "т" is quite common in handwriting, even though "*т*" is taught, yet the same is not true of *д* vs. *g*.

Comment: @RegDwight Nice point. And I do love handwritten Russian either way. But I was thinking actually of using ∂, because it tends to restore a, so to say, typographical equilibrium: in what I've learnt as [*handwritten alphabet*](http://masterrussian.com/graphics/cursive_russian_alphabet.png)– there are more hooks downwards than upwards. If I do my д upwards, it seems more equally distributed :)))

Comment: [Here](http://www.fontov.net/%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%88%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%82%D1%8B?f=%E4+%F2+%F8+%F9&st=0&c=1&t=0&s=3&ps=2) is a sample of fonts that emulate Russian handwriting. As you can see both styles of д are there. It's just a matter of personal style.

Comment: I also use ∂ in handwriting. This appeared spontaneously but have been found more convenient:) Another useful manner is to write э as ə, this keeps readability but greatly reduces writing efforts.

Comment: @Netch thanks, I'll ə a try. As non-native speaker, writing э has always been a headache for me.

Comment: @RegDwight Through my entire life i've never seen lower case т in cursive, although i do know a few ppl who write m and then put a bar on top of it.

Comment: The bar helps distinguish a m from a ш, so it's actually quite useful. Arguably т is just the next logical step in the same direction.

Comment: I switched to ‹т› in university when making lecture notes because it's much easier/faster to write and more readable than ‹*т*› (even with a bar). I guess most students who do handwritten notes switch to block printed letters when it's easier than "standard" cursive or improves readability.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both of the uppercase and lowercase letters you show here are taught in schools as the standard handwriting.

The typical uppercase handwritten form is either the one you provided or the block-letter style (Д). In my experience, more people are switching to block letter writing lately. I've never seen the lowercase д (g-style writing) or ∂ used in the uppercase.

The lowercase д (g) is ubiquitous. You may also seldom find a lowercase ∂, however this is exotic nowadays.

Answer (score 2):

*∂* is typewriting symbol and doesn't appear in standard handwriting. Some people use it as a decorative element, kind of like a monogram. But actually it's for typing (usually italics) only.

Answer (score 0):

*д* is italic. It is not a handwriting character.

Comment: Definitely it is. Have a look at Alexander Pushkin's [signature](http://www.thechroniclesofspellborn.com/character/batarchev.files/image124.jpg). Also, _д_ can be seen there in the first words of the 2nd and the 4th line. Or look at the 2nd picture [here](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BC%D0%BE).

Comment: @Yellow Sky sorry, but handwriting standard has changed very much from the time of Pushkin. Also he could be influenced by foreign languages. And anyway, an individual's style even if he is renowned cannot be taken as a reference.

Comment: :) They say, everything by Pushkin can be taken as a standard. Besides, what's handwriting standard? The one they teach kids in the 1st grade? As a practicing teacher I can tell you that by the 6th grade almost none of them follows that "standard" exactly, because it's too time-consuming and impractical. That's by no means a standard, just a guideline. As for me, I've been writing _д_ for decades already. No standard should or can suppress individuality, every handwriting is highly individual, so one can hardly speak about standards in handwriting.

Comment: @anixx yeah, that I know. The point is precisely that *italic font*'s origin is ...handwriting: Wikipedia says: "Italics: In typography, italic type is a cursive typeface based on a stylized form of calligraphic handwriting." So I find no contradiction. I just want to know, if I write like that, would be understood or people will think "ah this crackpot is writing so strange!"

Comment: @c.p. - Believe me, you will be understood pretty well, most people won't even pay attention to which shape of 'д' you use.

Comment: @YellowSky ну, тогда сделаю..., спасибо!