# What are these Russian characters that aren't in the alphabet in my learning material?

Tags: буквы, алфавит, typography

I have this comic book in Russian that uses characters I don't know from my Russian learning materials.

Please see my image. There are:

- small m
- и with line on top
- g
- mirrored s

Which 'standard' characters do they represent?

[image]

Comment: Out of curiousity, how did you never encounter `й`?

Comment: Here is a related/duplicate question with an extensive answer: https://russian.stackexchange.com/a/13538/4903

Comment: @Infiltrator i believe he did encounter `й` but haven't encountered specifically its cursive glyph ***й***

Comment: @БаянКупи-ка, да и может быть.  But he did correctly identify it as "и with line on top", so I am just curious why he did not equate that with `й` if he had encountered it already.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

-small m = `т`

-и with line on top = `й`

-g = `д`

-mirrored s = `г`

These are handwriting-style characters, but some of them (`m`, `-и with line on top` and `mirrored s` in particular) are also used in the italicized versions of some Russian fonts like Arial and Times New Roman, to name a couple.

Comment: Depending on your font setup, you may see them in context here: *который, куда, глава.*  If you don’t get those forms of the characters, copy and paste it into somewhere you can edit the font/style, and set it to italic Times New Roman (or most other serif fonts).  They’re very traditional alternative forms of the characters, both for handwriting and italic printed text.

Comment: @PLL interestingly, here in your example we can see the third variation of the look of `д`: like curved Greek small delta, similar to partial derivative sign. This seems to be a more common shape for in computer fonts.

Comment: you mean this? https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/2919/when-to-use-%e2%88%82-and-when-to-use-the-g-type-for-little-%d0%b4 :-D

Answer (score 29):

Those are cursive forms: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russian_cursive

The letters you were surprised by are, in order listed, Тт Йй Дд Гг.

Answer (score 9):

In some fonts you might also encounter 'mirrored 6' which is 'small д'.

Answer (score 7):

Nobody posted these letters italicized yet, so here you go:

- Тт *Тт*
- Йй *Йй*
- Дд *Дд*
- Гг *Гг*

Examine this answer's markdown by clicking "edit" to make sure I didn't trick you :ь

Comment: the lower case д is obstinate